# Problema com a chamada do FirebaseApp

Tags: java, android, firebase, auth

Tenho um fragmento que realiza cadastro e login de usuário utilizando Firebase. Porém, estou tendo problema com o método initializeApp(Context).
Segue o código:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

a mensagem de error:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
>   com.redentor.mikha.scientia. Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: Pode postar seu grandle ?

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo tenta ver se tem alguma atualização da API do firebase, e no código remova:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

E adicione apenas um:

`FirebaseDatabase fbDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`